# Android ImageView bitmap upscale mode

Tags: android

I'm generating an 8x8 pixel bitmap programatically, and setting this into an `ImageView` with `setImageBitmap`. The image view has a size (in the xml layout) of 100x100 dp.

When rendered, the image is shown very blurry. Is there a way to change the upscale mode to not stretch / blur the image?

EDIT, snipping from the xml layout

```
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Show the xml of the image view

Comment: 8x8 in a 100x100 ? Do you want to tile the bitmap? Or do you just want to show the single 8x8 bitmap in the image view?

Comment: Single bitmap... I wan't to see some big blocky pixels

Answer (score 0):

I need to display images of varying sizes in a full-screen `ImageView` with `scaleType="centerInside"`. Size of the images is unknown at the moment of loading but they are all in mdpi density and server cannot resize them on-the-fly. During the loading I have to upscale them so each image has the same size on different screen densities, e.g. 32x32 images should be scaled to 64x64 on xhdpi, 96x96 on xxhdpi by using the following code.

```
// R.drawable.test is located in drawable-nodpi
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
bitmap.setDensity(160);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```